# Angular 4 Error: Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matAutocomplete"

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Ugrading to material 2.0.0 beta 11 now I have this errors,
How can I fix it

```
<mat-form-field> <input matInput
    placeholder="{{'hotel.detail.labels.city' | translate }}"
    [matAutocomplete]="tdAuto" name="city" #city="ngModel"
    [(ngModel)]="selected.city"
     (ngModelChange)="searchCity($event)"> </mat-form-field>
    <mat-autocomplete #tdAuto="mdAutocomplete">
        <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="setCity(city)"
            *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city.name">
        <div class="row"><span>{{city.name}} ({{city.province}})</span> <span><small>{{city.region}}</small></span>
            </div>
    </mat-option> </mat-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

In your template, you are using `mdAutocomplete`. Change that to `matAutocomplete`.

This line:

```
<mat-autocomplete #tdAuto="mdAutocomplete">
```

to:

```
<mat-autocomplete #tdAuto="matAutocomplete">
```

---

In `app.module` or in your module where you are using material modules, check that they are prefixed with `Mat` and not `Md`. Also, the `MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE` provider in module `providers` entry.

Import the following in your module:

```
import {MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE} from '@angular/material';
```

And then, add it as a provider:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE, useValue: true},
    // ...
  ],
})
```

See this [**CHANGELOG**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta11-carapace-parapet-2017-09-21) and this [**Prefix Updater**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-prefix-updater). Link to working [**StackBlitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-beta-11-fsyxmh?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: I already use the prefix updater and added this provider to app.module

Comment: You also need to import `MatAutocompleteModule` instead of `MdAutocompleteModule`

Comment: It doesn't change `<mat-autocomplete #tdAuto="matAutocomplete">`

Comment: share your code in this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-beta-11-fsyxmh?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Ok maybe I understand I have `#city="ngModel"` and also `#tdAuto="mdAutocomplete"`

Comment: that doesn't matter

Comment: Now I have upgrade the packages to angular 4.4.4 and it seems work, before I have 4.3.6

Comment: @Alessandro That's because the angular dependencies have been updated to Angular 4.4.3: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-beta.11/package.json#L28-L34