# Angular 2, Material 2.0.0-beta.12 ng-material v1 compatibility mode

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a probleme with the new material beta 12. I got this error with mat-icon :

> Error: The "mat-" prefix cannot be used in ng-material v1
>   compatibility mode. It was used on an "mat-icon" element.

I have changed every md to mat. I have try to use NoConflictStyleCompatibilityMode (I import it and add it to @ngModule) but it didn't fix the problem.

Everything works in my main component, but when i try to navigate to a child component this error appears.

Any idea ?

**Fix** :
This error was due to Md2 package https://github.com/Promact/md2/issues/290

Comment: Follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46581863/1791913

Comment: It's strange, everything works in my app component but not in child component